# How to use this gem 'google-api-client' without requiring me to login my gmail account on every browser?

Tags: ruby, google-drive-api, sinatra, google-api-client

I'm developing (Ruby) **Sinatra Application**.

I currently used two gems:

- **gem 'google_drive'**
- **gem 'google-api-client'**

Here is the link i'm following [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby/) and [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/google_drive).

Why I cannot get any data via Google API, once my gmail was NOT logged in to browser?

Even I provided the required credentials:

- **client_id**
- **client_server**
- **scope**
- **refresh_token**

I **successfully** got data when my gmail was logged in on the same browser I'm displaying the image from Google Drive.

**Opening Connection:**

```
require "rubygems"
require "google/api_client"
require "google_drive"   

client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'Google Api    Client', :application_version => '1.0')
auth = client.authorization
auth.client_id = xxx
auth.client_secret = xxx
auth.scope = xxx
auth.redirect_uri = "http://localhost"
auth.refresh_token = xxx
auth.fetch_access_token!
session = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(auth.access_token)
@session = GoogleDrive.saved_session(@config_file)
```

**config.json**

```
{
  "client_id": "xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "client_secret": "xxx",
  "scope": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/"
  ],
  "refresh_token": "xxx"
}
```

Please help, on how to use this gem **WITHOUT** requiring me to login my gmail account on every browser.

Comment: In order to access private data you need to first be authenticated.   You are going to have to access the data with with every browser you want to access it with.

Comment: do you mean, using the account who owns the private files when generating refresh_token ?

Comment: Once a user has authenticated you should have a refresh token granting you access to a users files. However depending upon how the application was created by the developer the refresh token is normally stored in the browser some place as a cookie or a session value.   Loading a different browser it wont have the refresh token so the user will need to authenticate again.

Comment: The user was already authenticated, but when I used different browser, it seems that the refresh_token was not working. I cannot get any data.

Comment: If I authenticate your application using Chrome then with IE I will have to authenticate both times you cant share the refresh token between browsers.  its called client side.

Comment: Oh, i understand now, it's client side. Is there other way to fix it with the said gem ?

Comment: can any one there who can answer to above question